# How can I run many instances of the same React app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm a bit new to React and I have a very basic react project created using create-react-app. It's a profile based project with authentication and the user must register a profile before logging in. My questions is: How can I run two different profiles on the same app during dev ? So let's say I login with User: johndoe and at the same time I login with user: janedoe and I would like john and jane to see changes made by the other on a particular component. Is this possible without creating a new localhost server ?

A side note: I am using redux store to save all my states which means that my store gets updated on different pages within the app. I inferred from this that it is not possible to run 2 instances without updating over the same state in the redux store. I was hoping there was an awesome package or tool out there that I don't know about that could solve all my dev and testing issues for two different profiles. Any suggestion is appreciated as I am very new to react and have been working on it only in the last 3 months! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two different browsers, Chrome and Firefox for example.
It will do the trick!

Comment: Thanks so much Tarreq! That actually worked. Is there also an option to add a separate store for my redux so I can view separate store instances for the two profiles ?

Comment: Never mind. I just added the redux dev tools firefox extension and refreshed my app. Worked fine! :)